# Android Studio : how to simply display my 16x16 image to the screen?

Tags: android, image, sdk, imageview, scale

I'm new to Android Studio and I don't understand how could I simply display my 16x16 pixels image to the screen ?

I managed to display it at higher scale but that's not what I want, I can resize it with `imageView.setScaleX(0.1f); imageView.setScaleY(0.1f);` for example but I'm sure that's not the right way to do it.

Here is the xml code of the activity:

```
<ImageView
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/playerImage2"/>
```

and here is how I use this imageView :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerImage2);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_player);
```

How could I do to see my image with its right resolution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use android:src="@drawable/test_player".
With you want it to be 16x16px, change layout_width and layout_height to 16px.

Comment: Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_bg"
            android:id="@+id/playerImage2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer !